# Transformer winding tap switch without relay

Tags: switches, transformer

I have a transformer with four taps and I use two relays to switch between them:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT2Sfz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When both relays are energized, they consume ~60 mA which really is a waste. I want to switch between taps of transformer with something that draws less current.

I was thinking to use four logic-level mosfets but mosfets have an internal diode which will do unwanted half bridge rectification...

What options do I have other than relays and mosfet to switch between taps of transformer?

Edit:

[12 V Relays](http://www.tianbo-relay.kr/admin/pdfDowonLoad.php?productNo=310) are on the secondary side of transformer, relays and controller (MCU) are powered from another winding of same transformer which is independent from this four tap winding.

Comment: have you looked at SSRs (solid state relays?)

Comment: @BrianDrummond they use triacs, is it suitable?

Comment: SSRs will probably require 10 to 15 mA on the LED side so I don't think you'll save much. Which side of the transformer are the relays on? That makes a big difference to their power consumption. Add the coil specification into your question - not the comments. Also, indicate what your planned controller will be powered from. The DC output or something else?

Comment: @Transistor Added the extra info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use magnetic latch relays which require only a short pulse to set or reset.

Here's a schematic, using a diode matrix, 3 push button switches and 3 magnetic latch relays.

[image]

Freewheeling diodes for the relay coils and LED indicators are not shown.

'NO' contacts of the relays K1, K2 & K3 are to be used to select the taps.

How it works:

- The 'S' (set) coil of a relay switches the coil one direction and it remains there by magnetic action.
- The 'R' (reset) coil of a relay switches the coil in the opposite direction and it remains there by magnetic action.
- Pressing S1 momentarily 'sets' K1 and 'resets' K2 and K3.
- Pressing S2 momentarily 'sets' K2 and 'resets' K1 and K3.
- Pressing S3 momentarily 'sets' K3 and 'resets' K1 and K2.
- The diodes prevent backfeed from one switch into the circuit of either of the others.

Comment: I can't use diodes, they'll do half wave rectification. let alone voltage drop and heat...

Comment: Those diodes have nothing to do with the rectification. They are pure there to control the latching relays.

Comment: Only the normally open contacts of the 3 relays would be used to select the taps, as you have already done using 2 relays and their change-over contacts. The diodes are used only in the relay control circuit. So there's no question of half-wave rectification, voltage drop and heat.

Comment: Current drawn, only with the push button kept pressed, would be less than 200 mA.

Comment: @ElectronSurf: See the update.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much, Transistor!

Comment: Thank you, ElectronSurf.